# Use pace.js progress bar on page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pace.js

Here is what I want to achieve : To show progress bar on every page navigation (not a SPA).
So I tried :

```
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        showLoadingBar();
    });
```

This is **working fine in most of case**. But some how ***it is not compatible to every browser***. (It is not working in a Mac app which calls web view).

So I decided to go with some library like pace.js. Now this library works fine, on every Ajax request, but it does not meet my requirement. I also tried to set pace options like:

```
paceOptions = {
  ajax: true,
  document: true,
  eventLag: true,
  elements: {
    selectors: ['body']
  }
};
```

But it does not show bar on page navigation, (It only show bar while loading the new page, but I want it also show while page unload). So my question is : **Is there a way to show pace loading bar while navigating pages?**

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score -1):

This may help your needs.

```
window.onbeforeunload = renderLoading;

function renderLoading() {
    Pace.stop();
    // Enable the bar manually
    var paceEle = $(Pace.bar.el);
    paceEle.removeClass('pace-inactive').addClass('pace-active');
    var timer = 0;
    var intervalId = setInterval(frame, 100);

    function frame() {
        if (timer === 96) {
            // Clear the timer interval once its reached 96%
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        } else {                
            timer = timer + 1;
            // Increase the Percentage of progressbar
            Pace.bar.progress = timer;
            // Call render function to the progress bar and it updates the percentage of the loading bar.
            Pace.bar.render();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain your answer?

Comment: You can manually show the loading bar when the user clicks a link and redirecting to some other page. 

Pace.bar.progress is used to set the percentage of loading bar and Pace.bar.render() function is used to render the bar

Comment: can you edit your response and add this explaination